# Consume web service with PL/SQL: UTL_DBWS or APEX_WEB_SERVICE?

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql

I'm looking into consuming a web service from PL/SQL. There seem to be at least two possibilities, the package UTL_DBWS and the package APEX_WEB_SERVICE (and UTL_HTTP, but let's not go there).

Which is today the prefered one, running on 11.2 or 12.2, with Apex installed? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTL_DBWS is a PL/SQL wrapper over the JPublisher programs (Java Stored Procedures). It only supports SOAP.

APEX_WEB_SERVICE supports SOAP and REST. RESTful web services forms the prevailing architecture for the modern web. So if you have Apex installed why wouldn't you use APEX_WEB_SERVICE?

> "UTL_HTTP, but let's not go there"

For the casual Seeker, UTL_HTTP is the oldest of these packages and consequently provides a lower level API. For most use cases the higher level packages are the better choice.