# Consume a web service from an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql

I have a list of external web services that are used to retrieve bill information from a company. These web services are provided from this company.

Now, I want to consume these web services from an oracle db in order to post these bill information into my oracle database tables.

Please can anybody help me?

Thanks,
KLEDI

Comment: This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545659/consume-web-service-with-pl-sql-utl-dbws-or-apex-web-service). APEX_WEB_SERVICE is currently easiest, [but this page](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/web-services-and-the-oracle-database) has a good overview of all the options.

Comment: Thanks kfinity. Please, can you help me where can I find a more detailed example since I am new to this topic (on how to consume wb from oracle db).

Comment: Sure. Whether you're using REST or SOAP, this article has very detailed examples. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services

Comment: Thanks kfinity. It was very helpful.